# How do I get the maximum field value from a nested object in Elastic Search along with a specific filter condition where gender is female?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Below is the document in elastic search. How do I get the maximum field value from a nested object in Elastic Search along with a specific filter condition where gender is female? My result should fetch id as 34 and gender as female.

```
"abc" :
            {
              "id" : 28,
              "gender" : "female",
              "city" : South vales,
              "state" : "US",
              "gid" : 56,
              "value" : "Money",
              "type" : "Dollars",
              "date" : "2021-06-30",
              "edited_by" : "xyz"
            },
{
              "id" : 29,
              "gender" : "male",
              "city" : Mumbai,
              "state" : "India",
              "gid" : 55,
              "value" : "Money",
              "type" : "Dollars",
              "date" : "2020-06-24",
              "edited_by" : "hjk"
            },
{
              "id" : 34,
              "gender" : "female",
              "city" : Austin,
              "state" : "US",
              "gid" : 98,
              "value" : "Money",
              "type" : "Dollars",
              "date" : "2022-05-25",
              "edited_by" : "opi"
            }
```

I tried below and it did not work:

```
GET abc/_search
{
"aggs": {
"max_id": {
"max": {
"field": "id"
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Also `Elasticsearch` return documents. I feel your data model is not good for this kind of search. You would be better of by having  3 separated document, instead of just one.